# Network simulator2(ns2) using cygwin giving the error: "cannot execute binary file exec format error in cygwin"

Tags: binary, cygwin, execute, ns2

I am trying to run Network simulator 2 called as ns2 on windows10 OS using cygwin. For which i have downloaded cygwin n installed , keep all the files and directory inside the cygwin directory. When i am trying to run the srcript inside the cygwin, it is saying: cannot execute binary file: Exec format error". Please suggest or help.

Comment: ns2 can be used with a genuine "Linux OS", installed to 1) a hard disk partition 2) an external USB item. ... ns2 cannot work with Windows© 10 / Cygwin.

Answer (score 0):

Cygwin can only execute Cygwin compiled or native Windows executables.